# Tax implications of international funds transfer with dual citizenship

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, ireland

I have Irish and US citizenship. Are there tax implications if I transfer funds from my US account to my Irish account? I worked in the US for 13 years, but now reside in Ireland.

Answer (score 2):

Transferring money you own from one place to another pretty much never has tax implications. It might have other implications, including requirement to report it.

Being a US citizen has tax implications, including the requirement to file US tax forms for the rest of eternity.

Comment: Thanks for your info.I do file tax returns in the US and I am fully tax compliant but I was not sure if I would  incur  taxes in Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an accountant and this is not tax or other legal advice! :-)

Provided you were tax-compliant in Ireland for the tax years that the US money was earned I believe you are OK.

[This page](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/employment/migrant_workers/coming_to_ie_tax.html) makes the statements:

> **Income earned prior to moving to Ireland**
>
> - If you are moving to Ireland for the first time or you are an Irish citizen returning to live in Ireland and you were not resident or ordinarily resident when the income was earned, the position will be as follows:
> - Funds accumulated from income earned prior to the beginning of the tax year in the year that you become resident in Ireland will not be liable to income tax.
>   However, income other than employment income arising between the beginning of the tax year and the date of your arrival will be taxable if brought into Ireland, unless a double taxation agreement provides for a different treatment.

which seems to back this up.